# Stop audio playing on backpress

Tags: java, android

I have an activity when i click on play button and it plays mp3 sound. When I click back the audio still plays in the background and can also run alongside other audio sounds which is annoying. I have tried to implement other methods used on here but to no avail.

**Code:**

```
public class InstructionsManualActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_instructions_manual);
    Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.instructionsManual_but);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.instructions_manual);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}

}
```

**I have tried this code but app crashes on back press**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop(); // or mp.pause();
        mp.release();
```

Comment: you need to check if mediaplayer instance is not null then perform your code, check my answer below and let me know if you still face error.

Comment: You are declaring MediaPlayer in onCreate() locally, may be you are trying to pause or release MediaPlayer that you have not created. Just declare your MediaPlayer globally and create it in onCreate()

Comment: well said @GhulamMoinulQuadir , i have added an answer with added conditions to handle all these error case for him

Comment: I have realised that but cannot get it to work by moving it outside the onCreate(). Can you assist me in doing this?

Comment: take the code from the answer below , i have added the code and let me know what error you are facing if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all declare the MediaPlayer object Globally

```
  MediaPlayer mp = null;  //Declaring globally so can access anywhere in activity.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instructions_manual);
        Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.instructionsManual_but);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.instructions_manual);
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

> When you are pressing back button in any activity `onBackPressed()`
>   will be called , there you can stop you media player if playing.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
       //Here you can stop your MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked only when I set MediaPlayer mp = null; Thank you man!

Comment: @DavidG Your welcome buddy , feel free to accept and upvote

Answer (score 2):

```
    Try this it's working for me   

     if (mp != null) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
                    finish();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine just check it before stop for null player

```
    super.onBackPressed();
if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop(); // or mp.pause();
    mp.release();
```